# Read a list of dataframes from a CSV file in R

Tags: r, csv, split

I have a CSV file containing many dataframes with the same columns, for example:

```
x y z
1 2 3
3 2 1
x y z
1 3 2
2 3 1
2 1 3
```

What I want to do, is to load this data in a list of dataframes. For example, something like this:

```
$`1`
x y z
1 2 3
3 2 1

$`2`
x y z
1 3 2
2 3 1
2 1 3
```

Is there any fast way to do this in R?

Comment: A very similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286531/is-it-possible-to-read-two-tables-from-the-same-text-file/29287485#29287485

Answer (score 3):

We can read the file with `readLines`, create an 'index', `split` the lines with that 'index', and read it using `read.table` or `read.csv`

```
lines <- readLines(yourfile)
index <- cumsum(lines==lines[1])
lapply(split(lines,index), function(x) read.table(text=x, header=TRUE))
#$`1`
#  x y z
#1 1 2 3
#2 3 2 1

#$`2`
#  x y z
#1 1 3 2
#2 2 3 1
#3 2 1 3
```

Comment: did not see your answer. Mine is very similar but do not go through a second reading step (wich can be the bottleneck in term of speed for a lot of lines?)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I thought your answer is different as it reads first by `read.table`.  You can keep it as I don't know whether my solution is efficient or yours.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to read the file as such:

```
df = read.table(file='clipboard', sep=' ')
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  x  y  z
#2  1  2  3
#3  3  2  1
#4  x  y  z
#5  1  3  2
#6  2  3  1
#7  2  1  3
```

Add a column and split on that column:

```
df$V4 = cumsum(df$V1=='x')
lapply(split(df, df$V4), function(u) setNames(u[2:nrow(u), 1:3], c('x','y','z')))
#$`1`
#  x y z
#2 1 2 3
#3 3 2 1

#$`2`
#  x y z
#5 1 3 2
#6 2 3 1
#7 2 1 3
```

Comment: If `lst` is your output, then `lapply(lst, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, type.convert);x})`